# Why does a Build of my TypeScript project in Visual Studio ignore the TypeScriptTarget parameter?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript

I have an existing TypeScript project in Visual Studio (Express 2012 for Web). This project was created with TypeScript 0.8.1.

Some of the classes make use of properties and so require the `--target ES5` compiler parameter.

I have just now updated the plugin to TypeScript 0.8.2, and followed the steps defined [here](http://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Compile-on-Save) to enable "compile on save". This works as described, including compiling classes that use properties.

When I try to build the project, however, I get errors such as:
`Config.ts (32,6): Property accessors are only available when targeting ES5 or greater`

Here is the relevant section from my .csproj file:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" />
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
  <TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
  <TypeScriptIncludeComments>true</TypeScriptIncludeComments>
  <TypeScriptSourceMap>true</TypeScriptSourceMap>
</PropertyGroup>
```

The complete file can be seen [here](https://gist.github.com/sykesd/5033772).

Why does it work for compiling individual files, but not if I build or rebuild the whole project?

EDIT: updated snippet to show that the `<Import>` tag was also included.

EDIT 2: added link to gist of complete project file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you modify your .csproj file to also import the TypeScript .targets file (in lieu of the build event action to invoke TSC)? If you just update the PropertyGroup, you won't actually be invoking the compiler through the thing that turns those settings into command-line flags.

Edit: You need the `Import` tag to be after the `PropertyGroup` (otherwise the imported file doesn't "see" the property values you're setting). Ideally the `Import` would be last or near-last in the file - definitely after all the `PropertyGroup`s that change settings it depends on.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. Yes, I also added the <Import> tag, as described on the Save-on-Compile wiki page.

Comment: Can you post your entire project file (maybe on gist or something)?

Comment: I have updated the question with a link to the complete project file.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it - still learning how VS and MSBuild do things.